# Unreal engine Flip Flop always goes to A output

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to use a Flip Flop to alternate between two outputs, the function shown below gets called in a loop by a timer every 0,3s. The problem is that the Flip Flop only outputs to the A branch.

Shoot blueprint

[image]

Console output

[image]

I think the problem could be caused by the fact that the function is being called by a timer, but I don't know how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `Flip Flop` macro stores its state as a variable that is local to the scope that it resides in. In this case, the state is stored local to the function and as soon as the function ends, the state is lost.

Instead, you should consider placing this functionality in a macro instead of a function. That way, the state lasts for the scope of whatever the macro is being called in, which may be good enough for your needs.